# Check if JSON response field is null

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I am retrieving user fields from Facebook like so:

Comment: You need to check if `myInfo.education[0].concentration` exists, before you try and access data inside via an index.

Comment: looks like this was the issue! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This would be a good place to use the [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
if (myInfo.education[0]?.concentration[0]?.name != null)
```

If `education[0]` or `concentration[0]` is null, it'll skip the rest of the chain.

Comment: it seems the problem was I was trying to access the first index of something that doesn't exist (education[0].concentration[0])

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

(myInfo.education[0]?.concentration[0]?.name != null)

but I believe it will only work if the property is actually on the object ie the json section not missing. If education is not on the object at all, this will still blow up I think.

what I mean is

{
  "id": "757111564344608",
  "education": [],
  "picture": {

would work ok, but

{
  "id": "757111564344608",
  "picture": {

would throw an exception. The only way to maybe take it further is

```
public dynamic myInfo;
  myInfo = fb.Get("/me?...........
  Type type = myInfo.GetType();
  foreach (var pi in type.GetProperties())
      {
        if (pi.Name.ToLower() == "education")
          {
            var val = pi.GetValue(myInfo).type;
            //do stuff to get child elements based on value
          }
      }
```

the GetValue line might need to be changed, you might have to iterate through education's properties to find "type"